# convergence of power series of $S$

Tags: real-analysis

> Find the   domain of the  convergence of the  power  series of $S ?$
>
> $$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left (\frac {2 + (-1)^n}{ 5+ (-1)^{n+1}} \right )^n x^n$$

## My attempt :

I take  $a_n=\left (\frac {2 + (-1)^n}{ 5+ (-1)^{n+1}} \right )^n x^n$

Now  $\frac{1}{R} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |a_n|^\frac{1}{n}$

Now  i got $\frac{1}{R}=\left (\frac {2 + (-1)^n}{ 5+ (-1)^{n+1}} \right )$

After that im not able to proceed further

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

Comment: The limit does not exist. Instead of the limit, you should take the $\limsup$

Comment: When you take the limit as $n\to \infty$, the definition of $1/R$ will no longer have $n$ as a free variable.  So this "root test" for the domain of convergence is not properly applied.

Comment: okss@hardmath then  what test  will be applied ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split in the even and odd parts (this amount to reordering the series, but inside the disk of convergence the series converges absolutely so this is not a problem): 
$$
S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{6^{2n-1}}\,x^{2n-1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac34\right)^{2n}\,x^{2n}.
$$
The radius for the first series is $6$, while for the second one is $\tfrac43$. So the radius that will make the whole series converge is $\tfrac43$.

Alternatively, you can simply calculate that 
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left (\frac {2 + (-1)^n}{ 5+ (-1)^{n+1}} \right )=\frac34.
$$

Comment: thanks u sir @Martin Argerami